# Sort MySQL result by last value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have a MySQL table set up with a field called clicks. It contains the clicks on certain banners separated by space (e.g. "9 80 47 306"). The field's type is text.
I want to get the entire table row and sort by whatever the last value in that field is (in this case it would be 306).

What I have so far doesn't work (obviously):

```
SELECT * FROM banners WHERE active = "1" ORDER BY clicked DESC
```

Is there a way I can achieve this using SQL only?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the clicked column always in the same format, i.e. same number of elements / spaces?

Comment: In this case it would be rather confusing.

Comment: This is a horrible way to store data.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne No, the number of elements change.

Comment: @Ood it's clearly already confusing, you're loosing one of the main benefits of using RDBMS by storing your data this way.

Comment: @Jessica The data in this field is used for nothing else but sorting, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Ood and you can't use it for sorting as it currently stands so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `substring_index()` with -1:

```
SELECT *
FROM banners
WHERE active = "1"
ORDER BY substring_index(clicked, ' ', -1) DESC;
```

I should add that I agree that this is a bad way to store data.  You should have a junction/association table.  This would have one row per banner with a clicks column.

EDIT:

As the Joachim's comment wisely notes, we might want to change this to a number for sorting.  In MySQL, I prefer `+ 0` because it does not report errors:

```
SELECT *
FROM banners
WHERE active = "1"
ORDER BY substring_index(clicked, ' ', -1) + 0 DESC;
```

Ugg, storing numbers as strings.

Comment: @Ood You may want to cast to integer if you want numerical ordering; `ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(clicked, ' ', -1) AS UNSIGNED)`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:
Order by substr(clicked,length(clicked-3),3)